# How to check if the passed void function in a block is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

Are there any helpful hints how to check if the passed void function in a block is empty?

The output of the completion block is **__*NSGlobalBlock*__**, so the block isn't empty and check nil or NULL doesn't make sense ,logically.

**Have a look at the code:**

function calling example:

```
[aClass setCheckedItemVisible:YES animated:YES completion:^{
         //Empty block     
    }];
```

function:

```
-(void)setCheckedItemVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)())completion {
    ...

    (completion) ? ((void (^)())completion)() : NSLog(@"do other Stuff");

    ...
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass `nil` instead of an empty block? That way you should be able to check against `nil`.

Comment: These classes aren't for own use only. If any developer pass nothing, the event must still working.